Understanding the domain of a function raised to another function
So the question is to find the sum of all real solutions to the equation $\left(x^{2}-5x+5\right)^{x^{2}+4x-60} = 1$.
The solution intends us to take 3 cases:
The first case is to set the base equal to $1$, which yields two solutions ($x = 1$ and $x = 4$)
The second case is to set the exponent equal to $0$, which also yields two solutions ($x = -10$ and $x = 6$)
The third case is to equate the base to $-1$ and the exponent to an even integer ($2k$) which yields one solution ($x = 2$)
Adding these 5 values gives $3$ as the answer. However, my friends argued that the third case is incorrect as the domain of an arbitrary function $f(x)$ raised to another arbitrary function $g(x)$ can only be defined when $f(x) > 0$. A quick graph on Desmos also appears to align with this argument.
$x = 2$ being a solution." />

Your friends may be correct, but I'd argue (because I love to argue!) the question never said anything about function or the equation being a function that has a root.  It just says for what real values of $w$ does $(w^2 -5w +5)^{w^2 + 4w-60} = 1$  and if $w^2 -5w +5=-1$ and $w^2 + 4w-60$ is an even integer that certainly is the case! Or is it?  Again because I love to argue, it be argued that "a to the integer power" is a complete DIFFERENT concept than "base a exponential".  So I think this is pretty open ended. But I'd say -1 to even power should be accepted.

Had the question been.  "Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ via $f(x) = \left(x^{2}-5x+5\right)^{x^{2}+4x-60}$ find the solutions to $f(x) =1$" your friends would be right.  But as the question didn't say that and only said find real values of $x$ were the expression $\left(x^{2}-5x+5\right)^{x^{2}+4x-60}=1$, and as if $x=2$ we do get $\left(x^{2}-5x+5\right)=-1$ and ${x^{2}+4x-60}=-48$, so we get the evalution of $\left(x^{2}-5x+5\right)^{x^{2}+4x-60}{|{x=2}} = (-1)^{-48} = 1$, that is a solution and your friends are not correct.

Thing is...  We have concept of $b^n:  \mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ defined as $\underbrace{b\times b\times...\times b}_n$.  And we have the concept of $b^x:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^+$ where $b^x= e^{\ln b\cdot x}$ and $x^k: \mathbb R+ \to \mathbb R$ and these are completely compatible in the areas that they overlap but actually different things with different conditions.  The problem never states which one if any is being consider.  I feel we have to do all that work.
